# Create bug on failed release

Tags: ms-release-management

I have a customized Xaml TFS build that is building an SQL Server project and it's deploying the .dacpac file to a target database. In case of failure the build is creating a bug in TFS.

I'd like to move the "deploy" part from TFS build to the Release Management area.

It's possible to accomplish the same result with TFS Release Management? 
In case of release failure to automatically create a bug in TFS.

Update 1:
I was referring to vNext templates.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box? No.

You could easily write a PowerShell script or .NET application that uses the TFS API to create a bug, then call it in a "rollback always" block within an RM release template, though.